# Send form data using JavaScript Fetch and POST and then process it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, fetch-api

So basically I want to design my page in such a way that when a user leaves a comment, the page doesn't get refreshed, but the comment is sent and inserted into a database.

As such, I need to send the comment itself to the server, and I've read that the best way to do this is by using JavaScript FormData.The problem is that I can't get it to actually send something, and I want it to send to the server the data written in the type="input" element.
I previously did this by using the default way provided by the HTML form element itself: action=link method="post".

So I wanna append the id of the campaign to the url and send the comment itself to the server by using $_POST and JavaScript DataForm if possible, so it knows the campaign that should have that comment.

I can have multiple campaigns and they're all gonna be generated 'dynamically' so to say, with PHP alongside JavaScript scripts to handle their behavior, so that's why I echo'ed all of that.

```
<form id="commentForm' . $row['id'] . '" name="commentForm"  method="post" class="greyContainerAllCampaigns">
<input id="comment' . $row['id'] . '" name="CommentContent" max="250" title="max 250 alphanumeric and ,.?: etc chars" required pattern='.' \'[A-Za-z0-9 .,!?:\[\]()"-+]+\' ' .'class="inputBox" type="text"  placeholder="write here">
<button  id="commentB' . $row['id'] . '" class="submitButton" type="submit"  name="Comment">Comment</button></form>';
```

That's the JavaScript script I tried to write in order to do that:

```
          document.getElementById("commentB' . $row['id'] . '").addEventListener("click", commentFunction);

          function commentFunction() {

            fetch(\'http://localhost:80/proiect/GaSM/public/Campaign/comment/'. $row['id'] . '\', {
              method: \'POST\',
              body : new FormData(document.getElementById("commentForm' . $row['id'] . '")),
              headers: {\'Content-Type\':\'multipart/form-data\'}


            });

            alert ("You left a comment!");
          }

    </script>';
```

I tried to get the result on the server with $_POST['CommentContent'] but I get nothing, nothing ever gets sent.

I'm obviously doing something wrong with the way I try to send it via POST to the server in the JavaScript script but I don't know what. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

how about you give the form a class and in javascript add an event to this form whenever it is submitted to make an Ajax request to the form action with the data of thr e form serialized.

```
$(“.form”).on(“submit”, function(e) {
    $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr(“action”),
        type: “post”,
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(res) {
            alert(“success”);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(“error”);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Easiest way is to put hidden inputs in each form indicates to what campaign by id maybe

Comment: The comment will be sent automatically as long as it is a valid form element inside your form

Answer (score 1):

First, give your form element a normal id. Not sure what youre trying to do now, but if you want to use PHP to render it, use `echo` between PHP opening and closing tags: `id="<?php echo 'commentForm' . $row['id']?>"`. As it is now, I suspect your Javascript is always looking for a form with the literal string `'commentForm' . $row['id']'`. `row['id']` is not considered a variable.

Next, the syntax of this `fetch` function looks completely invalid. `FormData` works nicely with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), which I believe is what you're looking for.

For example:

```php
<?php
<script>
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Your logic for handling the response of the server
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (4 !== this.readyState) {
            // not yet ready
            return;
        }
        if (200 !== this.status) {
            //handle error response
            return;
        }
        // Handle something good...
    }

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://my.page/comment/' + <?php echo $row['id'] ?>);
    xhr.send(new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm')));
</script>
?>
```

Comment: ```javascript
let button = document.getElementById('thatFormButtonId');
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // insert AJAX code here
});
```

Not 100% sure if this will also prevent the form itself from submitting. In which case you could do something like:

```javascript
let form = document.getElementById('thatForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // insert AJAX code here
});
```

Comment: I get an unexpected identifier error with the first method at this line: javascript let button = document.getElementById('commentB1');  even though commentB1 is the id of the submit button of the form, and that's when I check it with chrome devtools/inspect element.Would send a picture if I could, would be easier to illustrate

Comment: In the code above, the ID you give the button is `commentB' . $row['id'] . '`, which looks very error prone to me. E.g. it has a whitespace as its last character, which might be causing you that error, as `'commentB1'` does not have that whitespace.

You are right though, would be easier if we could see something more visual.